# Get KendoUI Combobox id

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I need to use the same function for the change event in KendoComboBox.
No problems in binding the Javascript function with the Combobox.
Now I need to access the name or the id of the combobox inside the change handler.
How can I do this?
This is my code:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < (ViewData["alertLevels"] as List<AlertLevel>).Count; i++)
{
    AlertLevel lv = (ViewData["alertLevels"] as List<AlertLevel>)[i];
    <div class="col-md-2">
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m[i].contactTypeId)
        <strong>@lv.descrizione</strong><br />
        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(m=>m[i].contactTypeId)
        .BindTo(ViewData["contactTypes"] as SelectList)
        .Name("cbxContactType["+i+"]")
        .SelectedIndex(0)
        .Events(
        ev=>ev.Change("cbxContactTypeChange")
        )
        )
    </div>   
}
```

I need to access the caller combobox id in the cbxContactTypeChange function.

Comment: Please add more info, possibly some code examples you've tried, in order for us to help you better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the combobox change event: http://docs.telerik.com/KENDO-UI/api/javascript/ui/combobox#events-change

You can get the ID like this:

```
this.element.context.id
```

> **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/EXifI)**

Comment: Thank you very much! I was searching through the page, but I could not find that.

Comment: @PierpaoloParis, the browser dev tools and console.log() are your friends. Try console.log(this), and then in the javascript console you can expand the object and see all its properties.